# how to deploy ssrs reports to multiple business clients with no connection

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, deployment

We have system that we supply to several clients, I mean clients in the business sense (other companies).  This system includes windows services and a SQL Server Express database.  We would like to provide Reporting Services reports as part of the package.  We can develop them here, but how do we give them to our clients?

They do not have IIS and these reports will be viewable by their employees on their network.  They will not want to grant us access to their network.

Clearly, we could require that they buy a license to Visual Studio and we could send them the SSRS project with instructions for how to deploy to their database, but there MUST be a better way.

Any ideas?

Comment: remote into a pc that has access to network

Comment: Kostya - thanks for your response.  Remoting may not be an option.  Some clients won't let us for security reasons.  I need to send them a package by either email or a cloud service for them to do the deployment.

Comment: If they are on SSRS 2008r2 or higher you could just supply the SQL and RDL files (reports). But some manual setup of the SSRS Report server would be needed.  Document it, and offer to implement as part of the service, perhaps

Comment: we use citrix for that and they take care of security pretty well.

Comment: Kostya,  thanks for the reply.  I didn't know Citrix can do that.  In fact, I don't know much about Citrix, I will have to investigate.

Comment: Jerry, thanks for the reply.  They do have SSRS 2014 so this might be an option.  I didn't know you can deploy with only a SQL query and an RDL file.  Can you point me to any doc or thread that can fill me in?